# Plot highlighted line (categorical) over all background data in facets (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have time series data I'd like to plot in facets, but I also want the data of all the groups in the background of each plot.

Using the iris dataset for a rep-ex I want three facets based on Species

[image: facet_wrap by Species]

But I also want to have the lines of the other species in grey in each facet's background, making them easier to compare.

[image: Background Data]

I tried layering:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species)) +
  geom_line(color = "grey") +
  facet_grid(.~Species) +
  geom_line(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
```

To no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use `gghighlight`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
    geom_line() +
    gghighlight(use_direct_label = F) +
    facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]